# Spring beans from external spring context on classpath are not loading

Tags: java, spring

In my spring application config I am importing another spring application's config XML file.

I am doing this by using the import tag:

```xml
<import resource="classpath*:**/app-context.xml"/>
```

When wiring it up, my IDE (using IntelliJ 13) looks like it knows what to do. However when running the app, I get the `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. I have gone over this many times and I can't seem to find where I am going wrong.

I have made sure the the jar file in which the app-context.xml file is in my classpath, and it is!

I have tried looking at other posts on here and nothing describes or solves what I am going through.

Comment: How do you run the app?

Comment: where is app-context.xml located ? and how do you try to fetch bean ?

Comment: so the application I am trying to run is a batch job. It is kicked off via command line. Though at the moment I am simply trying to run it via the IDE (IntelliJ). app-context.xml is in the jar file common-services.jar

I am using spring annotations, so lots of @Aotowired. I kick off the application from the main method using:
    `ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/spring-core.xml");`

it is in spring-core.xml where the import exists